# How to create new .jpeg metadata in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, image, metadata, jpeg

I'm trying to add some extra information to image files when a user takes a picture in iOS.  Is there a way to add more key/value pairs to an image's metadata? I've been looking into the ImageIO framework, but everything seems to be a constant. This example in Objective-C is only editing certain pre-existing properties: [Is it possible to add own metadata in captured Images in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29946240/is-it-possible-to-add-own-metadata-in-captured-images-in-swift). And this Swift example allows a user to read the metadata stored in an image: [iOS 8 Photos framework. Access photo metadata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24462112/ios-8-photos-framework-access-photo-metadata).

Is adding new information to .jpeg images possible?  And if so, what is an example in Swift?

Comment: `CGImageDestinationAddImage` takes a metadata dictionary. There's also a newer API called CG(Mutable)ImageMetadata and `CGImageDestinationAddImageAndMetadata`.

Comment: It looks as though the keys for the dictionaries available from those libraries here are fixed: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGImageProperties_Reference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Individual_Image_Properties. Is there a way to add new properties somehow?

Comment: What prevents you from using your own keys? Have you tried it?

Comment: From the documentation: "The dictionary can contain any of the properties described in “Destination Properties” or the image properties described in CGImageProperties Reference." https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGImageDestination/#//apple_ref/c/func/CGImageDestinationAddImage

Comment: Long shot. Ever figure this out?

Comment: @shoe It's been a long time since I've worked on this, but I believe the I ended up using an existing field to store the data.

Comment: I see. So shoehorning data into a supported metadata field that's actually intended for something else, and then just keeping track of the unorthodox usage of the field?

Comment: I found something that was "close enough" for my particular use case. From what I remember there was more involved in creating custom EXIF data fields, so using an existing one was more expedient for me at the time.